# Running app on iPhone 3 with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to develop an app in iPhone 3 which doesn't update to 4.3.5 and stays in 4.2.

Xcode 4 only runs 4.3 so I cannot test an application on my iPhone 3.

I know I can set my deployment target to 4.2 and distribute it to iphone 3 users, but I want to test it on my iphone 3.

Does anyone know how to install iOS sdk 4.2 on my xcode 4 or simulating app on my iphone 3 (version 4.2).

Thank you.

Comment: What's an iPhone 3??? You mean 3G? Or 3GS?

Comment: i want to keep using xcode 4 and i mean iPhone 3 the one before iPhone 4, I'm not sure about the generation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xcode 3.2.6 or

use an ad-hoc distribution profile to get the app on your device.
http://furbo.org/2008/08/06/beta-testing-on-iphone-20/